# Light green mold on the top

Tags: ginger, mold

I am just starting my ginger bug. On day three and it has started growing light green mold on some of the ginger pieces at the top. I have it in a 1 L jar with an airlock. This exact thing happened the last time I tried to start a ginger bug just a couple weeks ago. Any ideas for how to keep the ginger pieces below the water?